# Open source solution for SIP based video streaming server?

Tags: video-streaming, sip, kamailio, opensips

I need to implement a SIP based video streaming server, which can communicate with SIP cameras as well as SIP clients on iOS/Android.

I'm investigating open source projects openSIPS and Kamailio, just want to know which one is more suitable for this application scenario, or is there another better choice?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) and [FreeSWITCH](http://www.freeswitch.org/) will be closer to what you want. SER derivatives, such as OpenSIPS and Kamailio, are oriented towards the SIP signalling  and I'm not even sure they offer any video functionality other than supporting the set up of calls that use it and possibly proxying the RTP.

However if your purpose is to connect directly to a SIP based IP camera you don't need a SIP server you can just place a SIP call to the camera directly using a softphone such as [Xten](http://www.counterpath.com/), [Zoiper](http://www.zoiper.com/) or one of the numerous other options out there.

Comment: What I need is just a proxy that can help SIP client to connect to SIP cameras and forward the media streams to the SIP client.

Comment: Although if you're only implementing the solution for personal or hobby uses you could probably get away with using one of the free SIP proxy services such as sip2sip.info.

Comment: Could you explain why sip2sip.info should be avoided?

Comment: Avoided? I was saying you should use it if it suits your needs.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it.